# License Permitting Customer Modification

Tags: licensing

I've written some software for a customer, and I'd like to release it to them under a license that permits them to make modifications for their own in-house use, but still prohibits them from selling or otherwise redistributing the software after I've given it to them. Can someone point me to a license that either has this effect or could with slight modification? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: 7 years later, I'd agree. It belongs over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ which did not exist at the time.

Comment: @Blumer This question is only borderline on-topic for Programmers. See the faq: [When is a software licensing question on-topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/when-is-a-software-licensing-question-on-topic) under "pick a license for me" questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no such license, and Googling for licenses gives a bazillion hits on the GPL and Open Source licenses...

You could try to look at [Free Software Foundations rundown on non-free licenses](http://www.fsf.org/licensing/licenses/index_html#NonFreeSoftwareLicense), and see if there is a close match to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that the license used by component developers that include source code might suffice. I'm guessing this is a commercial license you are looking for rather than a GPL or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write a proprietary license of your own?

I don't think you'll be able to use any of the existing published and explained licenses, since these are geared toward sharing and that's exactly what you're trying to avoid.